# PHPDoc - Dynamic Function Names and Return Types for IDE

Tags: php, phpdoc

I'm working on (somebody else's) application. I'm not sure what framework it uses if any, but it allows calls like this

```
Users:findByUsername('josh');
```

Which will return one instantiated User object/entity that matches that username. This seems to be being done by overriding __callStatic. Not an enormous fan, but would like the IDE to recognize the variable as a User object (or whatever class it's being called from).

Very ideally, I'd like the IDE to recognize that as a valid function or an alias of callStatic, but that's not a big deal.

So is there anyway to PHPDoc `findByX` as a wildcard? Or a better way to do it? The call static function is as follows:

```
    public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments)
    {
        if (substr($name, 0, 6) == 'findBy') {

            $turn_off_date_filters = (isset($arguments[1]) && is_bool($arguments[1]) && $arguments[1] === true);
            $additional_params = (isset($arguments[1]) && is_array($arguments[1]))
                ? $arguments[1]
                : [];

            $filter = array_merge(
                $additional_params,
                [\Helper::camel2snake(substr($name, 6)) => $arguments[0]]
            );

            if ($turn_off_date_filters) {
                $entity = static::where($filter)->withoutActiveDateFilters()->withoutAvailabilityDateFilters()->first();
            } else {
                $entity = static::where($filter)->first();
            }

            return $entity;

        } elseif (substr($name, 0, 9) == 'findAllBy') {

            $additional_params = (isset($arguments[1]) && is_array($arguments[1]))
                ? $arguments[1]
                : [];

            $filter = array_merge(
                $additional_params,
                [\Helper::camel2snake(substr($name, 9)) => $arguments[0]]
            );

            return static::where($filter)->select();

        } elseif (substr($name, 0, 5) == 'where') {

            return static::where([\Helper::camel2snake(substr($name, 5)) => $arguments[0]]);

        } elseif (substr($name, 0, 11) == 'deleteAllBy') {

            return static::deleteAllBy([\Helper::camel2snake(substr($name, 11)) => $arguments[0]]);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: See [@method](https://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/PHP/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.method.pkg.html)

Comment: I am using method to do every possible combination at the moment, no way to do it with a wildcard?

Comment: I don't believe such a feature exists. See [this](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor/issues/689) ticket. If you want to be able to autocomplete User objects, you can prefix the `$user = Users::findByUsername('josh');` line with a `@var User` annotation.